# Angular devextreme problem in error popup

Tags: angular, typescript, devextreme, abp

I'm using angular with devextreme , when an error occurs the error message is hidden behind the popup form , how can I send it to the front ?
thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the order in which you added the `dxPopup` Html Element. I guess your error popup is defined before the form popup:

```html
<dx-popup id="error-popup"></dx-popup>
<dx-popup id="form-popup"></dx-popup>
```

You should change the order to:

```html
<dx-popup id="form-popup"></dx-popup>
<dx-popup id="error-popup"></dx-popup>
```

Comment: error popup is built in , i didnt create it @marjay